# how to fill Combobox in vb 2010 with data from database (access database)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Sorry am a beginer to Vb, therefore am looking for a simple way to fill combox with data from access database.

**PHP WAY**

```
#connection first.

$sql = "select * from projects";
$select_records = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($select_records)):
echo "<form>";
echo "<select name='project">";
echo "<option name='$fetch[projectname]'>$fetch[projectname]</option>";
echo "</select>";
echo "</form>";
endwhile;
```

how can i transform the above code to vb[image: vb form with combobox]

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: for vb is `access database`, i want the code in vb using access database

Comment: do you know how to query in vb? did you already connect ms access to your vb code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        Dim query as String
        Dim con as OleDbConnection
        Dim command as OleDbCommand
        Dim reader as OleDbDataReader

        con.Open()
        query = "select * from projects"
        command = New OleDbCommand(query, con)
        reader = command.ExecuteReader()

        If reader.HasRows Then
            While reader.Read()
                 cb.Items.Add(reader("FieldName"))
            End While
        End If
```

`cb` there is the combobox name. Don't forget to import OleDb at the topmost of your code like this:

```
imports System.Data.OleDb
```

Comment: mac am having an error on Dim reader as OleDbReader; Error: OleDbReader is not defined

Comment: that was OleDbDataReader, sorry. I did that code without compiler so I got  it wrong.. it's good that you got it now. :) @SyntaxError